# Event Consolidation when there is no defined time window for Event Arrival

Tags: stream, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

We have a single topic called **migrationstatus**, assume we partition so that all instances and events for a given **MigrationCandidateNumber** always end up on the same topic and partition.

Following event arrives at 12-10-2019 at 10:00 AM

```
{
"MigrationCandidateNumber": 54545451,
"MigrationStatus":"Final Bill Produced"
}
```

Following event arrives at 14-10-2019 at 08:00 AM

```
{
"MigrationCandidateNumber": 54545451,
"MigrationStatus":"Product Ready"
}
```

Following event arrives at 17-10-2019 at 12:00 AM

```
{
"MigrationCandidateNumber": 54545451,
"MigrationStatus":"Registration Complete"
}
```

Problem Statement:

Once all 3 of those events have been processed, we need to produce the event below onto **migrationstatus-out** topic as shown below:

```
{
    "MigrationCandidateNumber": **54545451**,
    "MigrationStatus":"**Ready for extract 2**"
 }
```

The wide time window is deliberate, since the first 3 events could arrive days apart.

Best way of doing this with no external database?

Solution Tried:

1. You can't use windowed aggregation because we are not sure about when event arrives.
2. created 3 streams out of the main stream for different migration status but again stream-stream joins are windowed.
3. For this scenario I don't see a way to aggregate data so that we store data in KSQL table and perform a group by to check If messages with all the status has arrived.

I know its a wide open question and mostly related to approach for solving the problem rather than technical issue but I couldn't find a better forum to post this.

Comment: I would recommend to use the Processor API. Connect a state store to the `Processor` to store the data. This gives you most flexibility.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the response. It looks like a good approach. I have one more question. I found that Apache Camel aggregate can also solve this problem. please find the link https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html . Any thoughts which will be the better solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with Apache Camel. Can't give any advice. (Disclaimer: I work on Kafka Streams, so I have a personal preference---might be a little bit biased though :) )

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the response. I am working on it & I will post my findings here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and shared the code in github. Please follow the link for the solution.

[GitHub link for the solution](https://github.com/zamirarif/multiple-event-consolidation)

Thanks [MatthiasJ.Sax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953079/matthias-j-sax) for the heads up.

Comment: Please refer this article for more details: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-more-flexibility-using-kafka-streams-processor-api-zamir-arif/